# Combination with Repetition Variation

Tags: combinatorics, combinations

Say I have $5$ types of jellybeans and I want to choose $10$ total jellybeans.  But, for Type 1 jellybeans, I know I only have $5$ total.

How would I start this problem? I was thinking I would split it into two problems and begin by working with the other four types normally as $C(13,10)$, but then I'm not sure what to do with the Type 1.

Is this the right approach?

Comment: I would do it by setting the number of type $1$ beans and then choosing the others accordingly, then summing over the cases.

Comment: So, C(13,9)+C(12,8)+C(11,7)+C(10,6)+C(9,5)? then C(13,10) for the combinations for the 4 types if there are no type 1?

Comment: If you choose to adopt a case wise approach, you have to remember that for each case when you choose $0-5$ of type $1$, there are only $four$ remaining types from which you are to choose the balance.

Comment: If there are $i$ of type $1$ for $i\in \{0,1,\cdots, 5\}$ then there are $\binom {10+4-1-i}{n-i}$ ways to choose the rest from the other types.  So just sum $\sum_{i=0}^5 \binom {10+4-1-i}{10-i}$.  That's not quite what you wrote, so one of us is making an off-by-one error or the like.

Comment: I see, when I was considering the n value, I was still using $5$ and not $4$. $n-1 = 3$, so it would start at $C(12,9)$ if I were writing it all out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A way that doesn't involve summing up numerous cases is

- firstly assume that there are enough of type $1$
- deliberately create unacceptable solutions, by pre-choosing $6$ of the first type, with only $4$ more left to be chosen from the *five* types.
- subtract unacceptable solutions from solutions assuming enough of type $1$

Thus $\binom{10+5-1}{5-1} - \binom{4+5-1}{5-1}$